# SQL date format - producing different result

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a table Cdata that has DOB column and the column value are as below:

```
'1945-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

I am formatting the above to 'YYYYMMDD' format as below:

```
select  format(c.dob,'yyyymmdd') from dbo.Cdata c where c.cid='12345'
```

I am getting not getting the output as expected.

```
Desired output:'YYYYMMDD' format: '19450101'
```

Rexter link: http://rextester.com/NXBNZC17084

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capitalise the mm to MM in your format. As it is, it will return the minute portion of your date string. Try the following

```
DECLARE @A DATETIME = '1945-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
select  format(@A ,'yyyyMMdd')
```